# Postgis - st_MakeLine and st_lineLocatePoint

Tags: postgis-2.0, line, linestring, graph, position

Lets explain, I have 4 points (1,2,3,4), and I need to visit clients (A, B, C, D).

So, I need to use st_makeline with (1,2,3,4,3)...

Now I have to get % position from A,B,C,D; but in visit order.

If I do a st_lineLocatePoint, A, B and C, returns ok, but D, return first equal position (lesser that C).

[image: Graph]

How can I solve this? Some ideas?